# SQL server Warning: Fatal error 829 occurred at Oct 10 2019 12:48 PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator

Tags: sql, sql-server

The 2 table not insert or select or delete or drop table command  execute then show error below:

**The error I'm receiving**

> Warning: Fatal error 829 occurred at Oct 10 2019 12:48PM. Note the
>   error and time, and contact your system administrator.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SalesMaster_tmp]
GO
```

Comment: Ok. You have an error. And your question is?

Comment: how to solved this error

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick search on Google and find a similar thread [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/28574/ms-sql-server-2005-fatal-error-823). However, I extracted the possible solution for an easy reference.

Means there's an I/O subsystem problem. Is something called a 'hard I/O error'. SQL Server asks the OS to read a page and it says no - this means the I/O subsystem couldn't read the page in question.

The CHECKDB output means that it couldn't create the internal database snapshot that it uses to get a transactionally-consistent point-in-time view of the database. There are a number of different causes of this:

There may not be any free space on the volume(s) storing the data files for the database
The SQL service account might not have create-file permissions in the directory containing the data files for the database
If neither of these are the case, you can create your own database snapshot and run `DBCC CHECKDB` on that. One you have, run the following:

```
DBCC CHECKDB (yourdbname) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

Whatever the results are, you're looking at either restoring from a backup, extracting data to a new database, or running repair. Each involves varying amounts of downtime and data-loss. You're also going to have to do some root-cause analysis to figure out what happened to cause the corruption in the first place.

By the way - do you have page checksums enabled? Have you looked in the SQL error log or Windows application event log for any signs of corruption or things going wrong with the I/O subsystem?

Comment: System table pre-checks: Object ID 3. Could not read and latch page (1:784) with latch type SH. Check statement terminated due to unrepairable error.

Comment: Database error: Database 7 has inconsistent metadata. This error cannot be repaired and prevents further DBCC processing. Please restore from a backup.

Comment: Table error: alloc unit ID 196608, page (1:784). The test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. The values are 133129 and -6.

Comment: The engine recommends to `... Please restore from a backup.` Can you restore your DB from a previous backup?

Comment: sir do not any backup

Comment: Then your database is corrupt and you have probably lost at least some of the data in it. You might also have a bad disk. Start [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/help-my-database-is-corrupt-now-what)